# Import Xml into excel: Invalid file reference/ Invalid characters (CData)

Tags: xml, import, excel-2007, cdata, invalid-characters

I'm having some problems importing an xml-file into excel.

The xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <documents>
           <document>
                <name><![CDATA[ file1-123 ]]></name>
                <title><![CDATA[ title file 1 ]]></title>
           </document>
           ... Some more docs...
           <document>
                <name><![CDATA[ file2-456 ]]></name>
                <title><![CDATA[ title file 2 ]]></title>
          </document>
      </documents>
```

When importing into excel 2007, i get the following error:

```
  Invalid file reference.The path to the file is invalid or multiple schemes 
  are not found.
```

According to the claims of my colleague this error is the result of `invalid charachaters` in the `CData`. But i'm having some troubles believing him. The only characters i know that are invalid:

> { < , > , ' , " , & }

Yet the characters he claims causing the errors are:

> { Â , ç , ° , ³ , ë }

```
example:<name><![CDATA[ file1³-123³ ]]></name>
```

But those characters are in the `CDATA`

**Question:** How is CDATA interpreted by excel during import?And what are the characters that CData may **NOT** contain?

**Optional Question:** Why is `webutility.htmlencode` (this solved the issue, but not the question) needed when outputting CData (or XML in its extend) from `ASP.Net` website?

Thanks for your time